# How can I use poweroff without sudo?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. I want to use `poweroff` in my terminal, for traditional shut down of my computer. First of all, is this correct? Secondly, I am forced to use `sudo poweroff` and then enter a password. Is there a way to make the poweroff command such that, specifically poweroff command will no longer ask for sudo privilege, just commanding `poweroff` will work.

Thank you for your support

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? It works by default with 16.04 (or newer, I think).

Comment: @Melebius It is 18.04

Comment: @Melebius As I remember it depends on whether you are the only user that is currently logged in whether you need `sudo` or not.

Comment: @PerlDuck I am the only user, since it is my personal desktop computer. It asks sudo permission and password afterwards.